# initializing a structure array using memset

Tags: c, memset

gcc 4.4.4 c89

I have the following structure.

```
struct device_sys
{
    char device[STRING_SIZE];
    int id;
    char category;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct device_sys dev_sys[NUM_DEVICES];

    memset(dev_sys, 0, (size_t)NUM_DEVICES * sizeof(dev_sys));

    return 0; 
}
```

I get a stack dump when I call memset. Is this not the correct way to initialize an structure array?

Comment: If you typedef struct device_sys to dev_sys, you can retain the memset you have mentioned.   typedef struct device_sys dev_sys; memset(dev_sys, 0, NUM_DEVICES * sizeof(dev_sys));

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Either

```
memset(&dev_sys, 0, sizeof dev_sys);
```

or

```
memset(dev_sys, 0, NUM_DEVICES * sizeof(struct device_sys));
```

Or, if you prefer

```
memset(dev_sys, 0, NUM_DEVICES * sizeof *dev_sys);
```

but not what you have in your original variant.

Note, that in your specific case in all variants you can use either `&dev_sys` or `dev_sys` as the first argument. The effect will be the same. However, `&dev_sys` is more appropriate in the first variant, since if follows the `memset(ptr-to-object, object-size)` idiom. In the second and third variants it is more appropriate to use `dev_sys` (or `&dev_sys[0]`), since it follows the `memset(ptr-to-first-element, number-of-elements * element-size)` idiom.

**P.S.** Of course, instead of using all that hackish `memset` trickery, in your particular case you should have just declared your array with an initializer

```
struct device_sys dev_sys[NUM_DEVICES] = { 0 };
```

No `memset` necessary.

Comment: OP said c89, isn't that initializer c99?

Comment: @bstpierre: No. Why? Aggregate initializers were in C since the beginning of times (well, almost).

Comment: for your first example. &dev_sys. Isn't that the (address of). Like the address of the actual pointer. The dev_sys is already at pointer. If I have declared like this struct device *dev_sys. For the first argument I would have just sent the pointer dev_sys. Thanks

Comment: @robUK: `dev_sys` is not a pointer, `dev_sys` is an array. While it might "pretend" to be a pointer in some contexts, it is not really a pointer. `&dev_sys` gives you a pointer to the entire array, which is numerically the same as the pointer to its first element (which in turn is why you can use either with the same effect). If you declared it as `struct device *dev_sys` (a pointer), the `&dev_sys` wouldn't work. But when it is declared as an actual array (as in your OP), the `&dev_sys` will work.

Comment: @AndreyT - sorry, I was confusing that with the gcc warning "missing braces around initializer" that you'll get with that initializer. You're right, no syntax change there.

Comment: @AndreyT.
&dev_sys    [ 0xbf9ac874 ]
dev_sys     [ 0xbf9ac874 ]
&dev_sys[0] [ 0xbf9ac874 ]
&dev_sys[1] [ 0xbf9ac89c ]

The first 3 point to the same location. I displayed the 2nd element address for the last one. That is why I was a bit confused with either using &dev_sys or dev_sys. It seems to me that &dev_sys == dev_sys. Sorry for asking this question again.

Comment: Does initialize a struct with `= { 0 }` also good if u have pointer fields inside ? Are there any issues for that ?

Comment: @AnT Your firs example (&dev_sys) are absolutely wrong simply because _not all_ elements of structure are initialised by zeroes.  You can compile it and check by yourself as I did it.

Comment: @Dennis V.R: False. Apparently you did something very different. My first example is absolutely correct. And it *does* initialize all struct fields in all array elements to zero: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2eca19c7e8dbeca . I can't say what you managed to do wrong since I can't see your code.

Comment: @AnT You are right. The example absolutely correct. I've compared your and my code. I have the impression, that your first example compiler-dependant. And in my case I've used too old gcc version.

Comment: The first solution might throw `warning: argument to 'sizeof' in 'memset' call is the same expression as the destination; did you mean to dereference it? [-Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess]`. `2nd one is right`

Comment: @Rasmi Ranjan Nayak: Can't reproduce. And it is actually *not* the same expression as the destination. I suspect you are doing something differently from what is done in the question and in my answer. My answer is only valid if `dev_sys` has array type (as in the OP's code).

Comment: @AnT is the first option the best `memset(&dev_sys, 0, sizeof dev_sys);
`?  It seems the most readable and the least likely to make mistakes.

Answer (score 11):

There's a typo in your code.  Fix:

```
memset(dev_sys, 0, (size_t)NUM_DEVICES * sizeof(struct device_sys));
```

Picking good names avoid half the bugs.  I'd recommend "devices".

Comment: probably even safer way:
`memset(dev_sys, 0, sizeof(dev_sys));`

Answer (score 2):

For an array, `sizeof` gets you the entire size of the array, not the size of an individual element. The `sizeof` operator is one of the few places where an array is not treated as a pointer to its first element.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the `sizeof` operator the type and not the variable.

```
memset(dev_sys, 0, (size_t)NUM_DEVICES * sizeof(struct device_sys));
```

I prefer to use `typedef` for the struct.

```
typedef struct tag_device_sys
{
    char device[STRING_SIZE];
    int id;
    char category;
} device_sys;
```

The you can use `memset` as follows:

```
    memset(dev_sys, 0, (size_t)NUM_DEVICES * sizeof(device_sys));
```